# How to stream video live quality transcoding on 3 vps server

Tags: video-streaming, live-streaming

I would like to let the video stream on 3 different VPS servers with different IP. All technology nginx.
For the time being I let on stream 3 servers but the quality and the total bitrate is the same everywhere and yet I would divide it in 3 different quality that is:
Server 1: bitrate of 3000kbps
Server 2: bitrate of 1600kbps
Server 3: 900Kbps bitrate

Use of a method push rtmp from one server to I let 3 the same quality.
So how do I split it?

For now, it looks like this:

```
    rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935;
        chunk_size 8192;

        application live {
            live on;
            meta copy;
            push rtmp://11.111.111.11/live/stream-key;
        }
}
```

And it all works, but as I said before on the server, which method is called push rtmp is still the same quality.

About everything I read on the blog [TheHelpingSquade](https://helping-squad.com/transcoding-your-video-with-nginx/) did not completely understand all the issues because I am a layman.

Apparently you have to use the method exec ffmpeg just do not know whether this method will send stream to another server using the same method as the push.

Will you help me with this?